# How to find the best convergence rate of a dynamical system $x_{n+1} = g(x_n),\ n\ge 0,\ x_0\in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, limits-and-convergence

Let $\{x_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ be a sequence of reals such that $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$, where $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $0$ is a fixed point of $g$. My question is the following:

> > If for an initial condition $x_0$, we have $x_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, how should one proceed to find the rate of convergence of the sequence $x_n$?

I know that if $g$ is a contraction, then this rate of convergence is linear. However,

> > how should one proceed if $g$ is not a contraction?

For example, let $g(x) = x^2$. If $x_0<1$, then we have $x_n = x_0^{2^n}\stackrel{n\to \infty}{\to} 0$, and the rate of convergence is quadratic.

Note that if $g$ is Lipschitz, then I can always find an initial condition suitably so that the sequence converges to $0$ linearly. However, this estimated rate would only be an upper bound on the actual rate, as it was seen for the $x^2$ example, the actual rate is quadratic and is thus very fast.

Please provide some references to relevant literature. Thanks in advance.

Comment: But note e.g. that for $g(x)=x-x^2$, that has $g'(0)=1$, starting with $0<x_0\le1$ produces $x_n=1/n +o(1/n)$ (more precisely $x_n=1/n-(\log n)/n^2+o(1/n^2)$ I think)

Comment: A Taylor expansion around $0$ of $g$ should give you an answer for most of the practical cases.

Comment: @PietroMajer, for $g(x) = x - x^2$, I see that the convergence is sublinear. So I guess what I am asking should be applicable for superlinearly converging sequences.

Comment: @PietroMajer, also can you kindly tell me how you obtained the expansion for $x_n$? And can that method be applied to any ``sufficiently smooth function'' to get an idea of the convergence rate?

Comment: @PietroMajer, One other thing, for this particular map, the fixed point $0$ has the property $g'(0)=1$, which is why this is not a contraction, locally in a neighborhood of $0$. However, my situation is simpler. I want to analyze the rate of convergences for mappings which has $|g'(0)|<1$, but might not be a contraction globally. For example the $x^2$ map. Though it is locally a contraction at $0$, the convergence rate is actually quadratic rather than linear. I want to understand this kind of situation for general functions.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay: 1) consider the sequence $y_n:=1/x_n$, satisfying $y_{n+1}=y_n+{1\over 1-1/y_n}=y_n+o(1)$, so that $y_n=n(1+o(1))$, then  boot-strap.

Comment: 2) If $g'(0)=1$ and $g''(o)<0$ then locally the behavior is the same as for $x-x^2$.

Comment: 3)Assuming $|g'(0)|<1$ completely changes your question. Then g is locally a contraction (there is an invariant nbd of 0 where it is a contraction). In this case the first non zero derivative of g at 0 gives the convergence rate.

Comment: @PietroMajer, thanks for the comments, they were really helpful.

Comment: @PietroMajer: see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3276838/16078) and thank you for your comments here!